# Understand React-Redux Toolkit Syntax?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm new to react, redux and tyring to understand the redux-toolkit tutorial i follow. I have the slice as follows.

```
const initialState = {
  count: 0,
};

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: "counter",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      state.count += 1;
    },
  },
});

export const { increment } = counterSlice.actions;

export default counterSlice.reducer;

export const incrementTest = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(increment());
};
```

Then I use that `incrementTest` action as follows

```
<button onClick={() => dispatch(incrementTest())}> + </button>
```

I want to understand following.

In following fuction

```
export const incrementTest = () => (dispatch) => {
      dispatch(increment());
    };
```

we return a function which takes argument as `dispatch` then call that provided `dispatch` function with argement of another function `increment` which is defined above and exported.

However when we call this function we use `dispatch(incrementTest())` providing `incrementTest` as a param to `dispatch`. I don't understand this concept . Which concept in javascript should i further study to learn this ?

Also `increment` reducer take `state` as parameter ( and `action` also in some cases ). Who provide this (`state,action`) to this function as we call it as `dispatch(incrementTest())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this:

```
export const incrementTest = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(increment());
};
```

is an example for a thunk, a function that gets called (by a redux middleware) with two arguments, `dispatch` and `getState`. It is typically used to coordinate async work since you can `await` stuff inside the function or deal with promises. Look up the thunk middleware if you want to know more. I'm not sure why they made this action a thunk, there's no need for it, maybe testing.

To your second question, the library does. All you do is call `dispatch()` with an action, the library calls the reducer function with the current state and your action. Think of it as emitting an event. Your job is to create the event, the library takes care of updating the global state accordingly. The reducer is written declaratively, sort of. As in "how would the global state need to change if *that* specific event happened?".